# Voltar para página que chamou

Tags: c#, asp.net

Há alguma forma de eu fazer um código num botão sair, que me faça retornar para a página que chamou? Fixar a página não dá, porque esse página(consultaprocesso) é chamada de várias outras.

Fiz assim e está me dando erro:

```
<span id="sair">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="sairbutton" Text="[x] sair" runat="server" 
                    onclick="history.go(-1);" />
                </span>
```

Erro:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Source Error:


Line 643:               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Line 644:               <span id="sair">
Line 645:                   <asp:LinkButton ID="sairbutton" Text="[x] sair" runat="server" 
Line 646:                   onclick="history.go(-1);" />
Line 647:               </span>
```

Ele diz que falta um ")", mas onde coloco?

Não roda. Não deu mais erro, mas não funciona.
Meu script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function voltarPagina() {
            history.go(-1);
        }
    </script>
```

Meu asp.net

```
<span id="sair">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="sairbutton" Text="[x] sair" runat="server" 
                    OnClientClick="voltarPagina();" />
                </span>
```

Não dá erro, mas não volta para a página que chamou, continua na mesma página.

Comment: WebForm. Não pode ser Response.Redirect(url);

Comment: Passando a descrição da página chamado para a página "consultaprocesso" e ao clicar nesse botão sair dar um Response.Redirect para o valor recebido na descrição da página chamada. Tem algum impedimento para isso?

Comment: Eu não posso fixar a url de retorno, pois com redirect eu teria que definir uma página, porém essa página é chamada de outras então não posso fixar pelo redirect. Acho que tem algo em javascript, tipo um back ou algo assim.

Comment: Tentou com o history.back() ?

Comment: Retitra o LinkButton e faz o teste com o: <input action="action" type="button" value="[x] sair" onclick="history.go(-1);" />

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer a chamada via javascript:

```
<input action="action" type="button" value="Sair" onclick="history.go(-1);" />
```

Pode também ser utilizado a função:

```
history.back()
```

Caso queira chamar de um LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="sairbutton" Text="[x] sair" runat="server" 
     OnClientClick="voltarPagina();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function voltarPagina()
{
    history.go(-1);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Fiz uma edição para mostrar o erro que dá.

Comment: @pnet atualizei para caso necessite chamar de um LinkButton

Comment: Não funcionou. Fiz uma nova edição para dizer o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 0):

Para incluir uma resposta usando C#, você pode fazer isso usando a propriedade [UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Exemplo :

```
// static variable
static string prevPage = String.Empty;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if( !IsPostBack )
     {
         prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
     }

 }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Response.Redirect(prevPage);
 }
```

Porém use a UrlReferrer com moderação, pois a mesma utiliza o cabeçalho [HTTP_REFERER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), e alguns antivírus e extensões de navegadores podem apagar esse header do request.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o problema estava no LinkButton. Alterei e funcionou.

```
<a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Voltar a pagina Anterior</a>
```